# Querying substrings against a list of values

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing

I'm reading from a dataset that I unfortunately don't have the access to modify. It has concatenated strings of values, and I want to select records for which any of those substrings (as split by a given character) matches any of the values in a specific list. I'll be passing the queries in via Python, so it won't be compared against a static list.

For example, the table looks like:

```
CrappyColumn
-----------
1;2
4
1
2;1
1;3
2
```

And I might want to return anything that has 2 or 4 in it. So, my result should be:

```
1;2
4
2
2;1
```

I have played with regexp_substr and gotten something that actually works; however, it just runs indefinitely (as much as 10 minutes before I give up) when I run it on the full dataset (which only includes about three thousand records with values that are often a couple hundred characters long). I need something that works in a reasonable amount of time for repeated execution.

I realize that--even with a variable comparison list--*I could just write my Python code to parse the list and construct multiple LIKE statements, but that seems inefficient, and I assume that there is a better way.*

And here's what I've done that takes too long:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CrappyColumn
   FROM 
     (SELECT DISTINCT CrappyColumn, regexp_substr(CrappyColumn, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) as UGH
          FROM CrappyTable
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(CrappyColumn, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
WHERE UGH IN ('2', '4')
```

Is there a better, faster, cleaner way to accomplish this?

EDIT - RESOLUTION:

Thanks to vkp's help, here is what I implemented:

```
regexp_like(SITE_ID, '^(2|4)(:)|(:)(2|4)(:)|(:)(2|4)$|^(2|4)$')
```

I modified it for my final product, so that it can handle strings of more than one character--by changing `[2|4]` to `(2|4)`. This works in cases of searching for numbers that aren't single-digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler method would be to use `regexp_like` to check if the list has `2` or `4` in it.

```
select *
from tablename
where regexp_like(crappycolumn,'^[2|4][^0-9]|[^0-9][2|4][^0-9]|[^0-9][2|4]$|^[2|4]$')
```

- `^[2|4][^0-9]` - Starts with 2 or 4 not followed by a digit.
- `[^0-9][2|4][^0-9]` - 2 or 4 not succeeded or preceded by a digit.
- `[^0-9][2|4]$` - Ends with 2 or 4 not preceded by a digit.
- `^[2|4]$` - 2 or 4 is the only character in the string.

Comment: All of these solutions work, but this is the cleanest, simplest one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `like`:

```
select t.*
from crappytable t
where ';' || crappycolumn || ';' like '%;2;%' or
      ';' || crappycolumn || ';' like '%;4;%';
```

You seem to know that storing lists of values in a single column is a bad idea, so I'll spare the harangue ;)

EDIT:

If you don't like `like`, you can use `regexp_like()` like this:

```
where regexp_like(';' || crappycolumn || ';', ';2;|;4;')
```

Comment: Thanks. I assumed there was another way, since I'll be passing multiple sets of values to the queries. But I may just have to have my script construct the multiple LIKE queries each time.

Answer (score 0):

Another form of regexp_like().  This regex looks for 2 or 4 only when proceeded by the beginning of the line or a semi-colon and when followed by a semi-colon or the end of the line:

```
SQL> with crappy_tbl(crappy_col) as (
     select '1;2' from dual union
     select '4' from dual union
     select '1' from dual union
     select '2;1' from dual union
     select '1;3' from dual union
     select '2' from dual union
     select '22;;44;' from dual
   )
   select crappy_col
   from crappy_tbl
   where regexp_like(crappy_col, '(^|;)(2|4)(;|$)');

CRAPPY_
-------
1;2
2
2;1
4

SQL>
```