# Match a delimited substring against a list from a query

Tags: mysql, regex, parsing

I'm looking at a column (`Codes`) in a mySQL table that has a series of codes delimited by ';'.

```
id | Codes
------------
01 | O5.12;Z33.9;A70.2;PR96
02 | A57.0;Z64.88;OA100  
03 | O7.99;PR1;CO45
```

I also have a second set of data: a list of code types and codes belonging to each type. Currently they are organized like this (although this structure can be changed):

```
CodeType | Code
--------------------
HR-PT    | Z33.9
HR-PT    | O5.12
NCS      | PR96
NCS      | CO96
```

The problem: For each record in the first table, I want to say whether any of the codes belong to a particular set. It's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379583/querying-substrings-against-a-list-of-values), which I solved like this:

```
select Codes regexp '(^|.*;)(Z33[.]9|O5[.]12)(;.*|$)') as HRPT_Code
```

However, rather than a static list, I'd like to dynamically pull the HR-PT codes to check against, e.g. using something along the lines of `select Code from code_types where CodeType='HR-PT'`

Any ideas how to accomplish this efficiently?

Comment: Don't store delimited lists in columns. Normalize your schema and put them in a separate table, one value per row.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the ability to change the first data source.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having to faf around with regexes, you could [`replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) the delimiters with commas (`,`), and then use [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT id
FROM   codes c
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   code_types ct
               WHERE  ct.code_type = 'HP-PT' AND
                      FIND_IN_SET(ct.code, REPLACE(c.codes, ';', ',')) > 0)
```

Comment: One caveat: this won't work if any of the codes could contain comma.